# Binding `S-mouse-1`

Tags: key-bindings, mouse

I'm trying to bind `S-mouse-1` which doesn't seem to be as easy as I thought. So far I'm using:

```
(define-derived-mode foobar-mode nil "foobar")

(define-key foobar-mode-map [S-down-mouse-1]
  (lambda () (interactive)))

(define-key foobar-mode-map [S-mouse-1]
  (lambda () (interactive) (message "S-mouse-1")))
```

This seems to work but looks really clumsy. Is there a better way to do this? Without this clumsy binding of `S-down-mouse-1` I do not get rid of its original binding to `'mouse-appearance-menu`.

Note: Eventually I want to put this keymap into a text-property. This is why I want to override this key-binding and not remove it globally.

Comment: I suspect an 'X - Y' problem here. If you want some text to have a mouse action, you should look into `make-text-button` or `make-button`

Comment: FWIW, I don't think it's an X-Y problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I think what you did is what most of us do in such a context.
A mouse click involves a down (press) and an up (release) event. If you bind a command to the up event then you typically need to disable any command that might be bound to the down event.

See the Elisp manual, node [Click Events](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Click-Events.html).

But you can use this, instead; it's a bit simpler:

```lisp
(define-key foobar-mode-map [S-down-mouse-1] 'ignore)
```

Comment: Yes, this is much better. (I didn't know that a function `ignore` existed.) One more question: Why is `mouse-appearance-menu` bound to `S-down-mouse-1` at all? Would `S-mouse-1` not be sufficient?

Comment: A mouse click involves a down (press) and an up (release) event. If you bind a command to the up event then you typically need to disable any command that might be bound to the down event. Displaying a menu with a mouse click for example: some like to bind it to the down event, and some like to bind it to the up event; and sometimes the particular platform can influence the choice.